# Robot Framework - how to strip out javascript tags from html using Remove String Using Regexp keyword

Tags: html, regex, robotframework

I working on a test case that visits a page, gets the page source and saves it into an html file.  Before saving the source code, I need to strip out all javascript from "" to "".  I've gone through numerous online resources and come up with `<script type="text/javascript">([\\s\\S]*?)<\\/script>` but the regular expression syntax I enter into the test case does not seem to work.  Does anyone have any suggestions?

More Info:
The page source code contains many instances of JavaScript and spans multiple lines so I believe I need to prefix the expression with `(ims)`.  In my solution above, you'll also see that I've escaped the backslashes since I read somewhere that it was necessary.

Example of the source code:

```html
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
some multiline javascript
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript"> some single line javascript  </script>
<body>
body content
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
some more javascript
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my try:

```
"<script[^>]*>[^\0]*?<\/script>", gi
```

---

[Regex live here.](https://regex101.com/r/sL6oY9/5)

Explaining:

```
#   <script              # match the start of the tag
#   [^>]*>               # match anything till the ">" character
#   [^\0]*?<\/script>    # match anything (not null) till the closing tag
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.  I've used your expression but my test run still does not seem to remove the javascript when I insert it into the Remove String Using Regexp keyword.  I've tried the following versions of your regex: "<script[^>]*>[^<]*<\/script>", gi, (ims)<script[^>]*>[^<]*<\/script>, <script[^>]*>[^<]*<\/script>,gi

Comment: Using <script[^>]*>[^<]*<\\/script> alone seems to have done the trick!  It looks like the keyword I'm using automatically scans through and removes even multi line matches.  Thanks!

Comment: My first attempt of solving it will crash if any javascript code contains "<" character, so I've updated to fix that.

Comment: Scratch that.  I forgot to add in some escape characters for the backslash.  Works fine!  thanks again